Unity Missile Moves Downwards Instead of Forward
I'm working on a missile script in Unity, and I've encountered an issue where my missile moves downwards instead of following the intended direction towards the target. Here's the relevant code I'm using:
void Update()
{
    if (target == null)
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        Debug.LogError("No target assigned for the missile!");
        return;
    }

    Vector3 direction = (target.position - transform.position).normalized;

    Quaternion lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, lookRotation, rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    transform.position += direction * speed * Time.deltaTime;
}

I've tried using tansform.forward and transform.up to see if the missile would work as intended but both of them make the missile move weird (i dont really know how to describe it)
It is important to note that the missile moves in the desired direction, but it also moves downward, causing it to never hit the target.

If the missile object has a rigidbody attached, it will be affected by the gravity.

If you are using a rigidbody, do not modify the transform directly. Use physics instead

i dont really know how to describe it Create a GIF and upload it here.

You can use Rigidbody.Move or Rigidbody.MovePosition or Rigidbody.MoveRotation.

Disable property Use Gravity on the missile's Rigidbody, or compensate for it in the targeting system if you want more realism.
